# wp_editor is not rendering shortcode

Tags: widgets, dashboard, wp-editor

I have created a dashboard widget and this widget will show content which i'll add from an specific page.
So, i created a option page and made a textarea field with wordpress editor.

```
wp_editor(html_entity_decode(stripcslashes($widget_content)), 'widget_wp_content');
```

But when i am calling this field value in widget area than its giving correct image as image not image html. But for caption its showing caption shortcode.like

```
 [caption id="attachment_25613" align="alignnone" width="200"]image display and caption_content[/caption].
```

I am using code to print value is

```
echo  html_entity_decode(stripslashes($val['content']));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run it through `do_shortcode()`. `do_shortcode()` 'runs' any shortcodes in text passed to it:

```
echo do_shortcode( html_entity_decode( stripslashes( $val['content'] ) ) );
```

Comment: yes, i just corrected that to echo do_shortcode(wpautop(stripslashes($options['content'])))

Comment: Your answer is working. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to enable shortcode in your widget ?

```
add_filter('widget_text','do_shortcode');
```